# Ruin probability is independent of initial time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Currently I am reading [Notes on Markov Chains](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MAS328/MAS328-5.pdf).

Context: We consider an amount of $S$ dollars which is to be shared
between two players A and B.
We let $X_n$ represent the wealth of Player A at time $n \in \mathbb{N}.$
We let $R_A$ to be Player A loses all his capital at some time, that is,
$$R_A = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{X_n=0\}.$$

At page $54,$ Lemma $2.2$ is stated as follows:

> For all $k=1,2,...,S-1,$ we have 
>   $$\mathbb{P}(R_A|X_1 =k\pm 1, X_0=k) = \mathbb{P}(R_A|X_1 =k\pm 1) = \mathbb{P}(R_A| X_0=k\pm 1).$$
>   In other words, the ruin probability depends on the data of the starting point
>   and not on the starting time.

My question is

> **Question:** How to show the second equality directly, that is, 
>   $$\mathbb{P}(R_A|X_1 =k\pm 1) = \mathbb{P}(R_A| X_0=k\pm 1)?$$

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You have made a typo here - the equality is $\mathbb{P}(R_A \mid X_1 = k \pm 1) = \mathbb{P}(R_A \mid X_0 = k \pm 1)$. There is a proof on page 54-55 and you can see the second last step is a crucial one. The intuitive explanation is that no matter you shift the index of sequence by how much (whenever it is a finite constant), it will not affect the probability of the absorption in a certain state. It is a tail event (correct me if I am wrong) and you may analog this situation in convergence of sequence.

Comment: This is the fact that $(X_{n+1})_{n\geqslant0}$ conditionally on $[X_0=k,X_1=k+1]$, say, is distributed as $(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ conditionally on $[X_0=k+1]$. Likewise for $[X_0=k,X_1=k-1]$. Thus, put concisely, this is the (simple) Markov property at time $1$ (and the time homogeneity of the process, if you want to be complete). A small caveat though: this assumes that $k+1\ne0$ and $k-1\ne0$.